# Как настроить отношения User Model в Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется две модели. **User** (получена в результате *make:auth*) и **Ad**. Модель **Ad** наследует **Model**, а модель **User** наследует **Authenticatable**.

В результате чего при попытке назначить отношения между моделями, я получаю ошибку:

> General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Модель Ad имеет функцию:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Модель User имеет функцию:

```
public function ads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Ad');
    }
```

В чем проблема и как решить?

Comment: Если разговор заходит об отношениях, то стоит о них написать - опишите поля таблиц, напишите, как вы их назначаете.

Comment: Возможно у вас таблица уже не пустая и там есть пустые поля user_id, или не пустые но со значениями которых нет в user_id ?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам следует создать в таблице `ads`, `user_id` int поле и при создание `ad` записывать в `user_id` id пользователя

```
         ADS table
    id        |    int
    slug      |    string
    name      |    string
    content   |    text
    user_id   |    int
```

AdController

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['slug' => 'required|alpha|unique:ads', 'name' => 'required', 'content' => 'required']);
    $Ad = new Ad;
    $Ad->slug = $request->slug;
    $Ad->name = $request->name;
    $Ad->content = $request->content;
    $Ad->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $Ad->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```